# What's the best way to adjust a leaning gate post?

Tags: fence, gate-post

I recently built a large double wood gate using 6x6x8 posts.  Each post was set with concrete in a 26" hole.   After some settling, one of the posts is now leaning about 1/4 inch toward the middle.  This is causing the gate to not open/close easily.  What is the best way to adjust the leaning post?  Or do I need to redo the post setting entirely?

Answer (score 7):

My first thought is a guy wire from the top corner of the post, with a turnbuckle in the middle to tension it up and pull out that lean in the post. It seems that if you don't do something like this, the only alternative IS to reset the posts, which is a lot of work.
Hope this helps.

This is what a turnbuckle looks like:

[image]

Comment: you beat me to it while I was trying to figure out what a turnbuckle was actually called! I have something similar on my backyard gate. The screw eye attaches to the top corner of the leaning post, and runs a cable with a turnbuckle to the bottom of the adjacent post, also attached with a screw eye. That way the moment arm from the base is maximized for the leaning post and minimized for the stabilizing post, resulting in less of a chance for them **both** to start leaning towards each other.

Comment: What would you do if the leaning post is in a corner?  i.e., the gate is at a 90 degree angle from the fence.  My guess is you'd have to turnbuckle it to the ground then...not ideal, since that's the neighbor's yard :P

Comment: I know I'm coming in a decade after the question was asked, but how to attach the guy wire may not be obvious.  In case someone comes here looking, there's good article on how to do it right here: https://extremehowto.com/stabilize-a-leaning-fence/.  Be sure to pay attention to the part titled "Don’t Saddle a Dead Horse."

Answer (score 1):

Why not stick a 1/4" shim behind the gate's lower hinge? Or planing off 1/4" behind the upper hinge?

Answer (score -1):

I happen to have the same problem.  Used turnbuckle and cable.  Actually anchored it to the base of some large arbor vitae adjacent to the 90 degree fence/gate.  Works so far turn buckle adjusts making it.plumb. used spacer as not to kill the arbor vitae .  My only other solution was to drive a metal post deep into the soil just adjacent and attach cable to it.  Couldn't  cement the it because property on other side was not mine and deep cocert already poured prevented it.  Used 1/2 cement anchors with metal  post base.  All in all not a fun project but enjoyed the challenge.  Adjust a gates made preventing sag nice.